# Fetching only a part of a table in Excel based on a criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, conditional-statements, analytics

I want to get a table with SUPNO, VALUE and LT for SUPNO = S1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GxmF.png)

Comment: Excel version?  Also, is your table an Excel table or just a flat range?  If you have EXCEL 365, you can use FILTER for this.

Comment: Excel 365 Version

Answer (score 0):

OK - if this is just a flat range, then you can do:

```
=INDEX( FILTER( A1:E21, C1:C21="S1"), SEQUENCE( COUNTIF( C1:C21, "S1" ) ), {3,4,5} )
```

Comment: I did not include your headers - let me know if that matters.